# Solving log/exponent equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've transformed the number 11 to:

$11^e = 677.32$

Given the exponent and the transformed value, how can I solve for the original number?

I know that $x = y^z$ and that $z = \log_y(x)$, but I don't know how to solve for $x$? Can anyone explain how I can use the exponent $e$ and $677.32$ to find the $x$ value of 11?

Comment: Why did you choose the letter $e$ in the exponent? That makes the question difficult to understand, if you're not referring to the number $e$.

Comment: Yes, I'm referring to the constant $e$, (2.718).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want $x$ to satisfy $x^e=b$, then what you are looking for is $\sqrt[e]{b}$ or $b^\frac1e$.

Answer (score 0):

This is equation with constant e (2.71) as exponent and no obvious unknown quantities. We can set equation with one unknown from Rasmus's answer (the general solution). However, the terms can be manipulated with the rules of logs and exponents, assuming work uses natural logarithms for base e.

```
    1. a**b=c        definition of exponent
    2. x=c**(1/b)    Rasmus's answer (from general solution)
    3. loading terms, x=677.32**(1/2.71) or 11.0
    4. check answer.  11**2.71 approximates 664
```

Refs

```
               1. Exponentiation with arbitrary bases, exponents,   Math 152, section

               2. 55, Vipul Naik , pdf on internet 

               3.   Wikipedia, exponentiation
```